# how to update pivot table which has more than 1 pivot column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many, pivot-table

I have 3 tables; `periode`, `santri`, and `periode_santri`(pivot table). I got trouble when I wanted to update it, because I've more than one column pivot

My controller is like this:

```
public function editangka(Request $request, $id)
{
    $santri = Santri::find($id);
    $data = [
        'kbm_h'=>$request->value1,
        'kbm_i'=>$request->value2,
        'kbm_a'=>$request->value3,
        'kbm_t'=>$request->value4,
        'kbm_s'=>$request->value5,
        'kbm_ct_ss'=>$request->value6,
        'kbm_jum_sam'=>$request->value7,
        'kbm_min'=>$request->value8,
        'kgt_h'=>$request->value9,
        'kgt_i'=>$request->value10,
        'kgt_a3_a5'=>$request->value11,
        'kgt_a4_a6'=>$request->value12,
        'kgt_d3'=>$request->value13,
        'kgt_a8'=>$request->value14,
        'kgt_t'=>$request->value15,
        'kgt_nomin'=>$request->value16,
        'kgt_jum_sam'=>$request->value17,
        'kgt_min'=>$request->value18,
        'pkt_yes'=>$request->value19,
        'pkt_no'=>$request->value20,
        'pkt_total'=>$request->value21,
        'pkt_min'=>$request->value22,
        'pu_kode'=>$request->value23,
        'pu_min'=>$request->value24,
        'tot_min_kbm'=>$request->value25,
        'tot_min_kgt'=>$request->value26,
        'tot_min_pkt'=>$request->value27,
        'tot_min_pu'=>$request->value28, 
        'saldo_poin'=>$request->value29, 
        'ket'=>$request->value30
    ];
    $santri->periode()->UpdateExistingPivot($request->pk, $data);
}
```

then, the message that I got is like this:

```
"line": 55,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
"type": "->"
},enter code here
{
"file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pipastibisa\\server.php",
"line": 21,
"function": "require_once"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing multiple single-element arrays to the `UpdateExistingPivot()` method when it should be only one as a second argument.

This is the method signature:

```
public function updateExistingPivot($id, array $attributes, $touch = true) {/** ... */}
```

As you can see, the first argument is the key, then the second one is an array that holds all the pivot data to update. The last argument is to touch (update the `updated_at` field) the parent models.

Let me fixed it for you:

```
public function editangka(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = [
        'kbm_h' => $request->value1,
        'kbm_i' => $request->value2,
        'kbm_a' => $request->value3,

         // ... all of your fields..

        'ket'   => $request->valueN
    ];

    $santri->periode()->UpdateExistingPivot($request->pk, $data);
}   //                                                    ^^^^^
```

Comment: sorry sir, but it doesn't work,

I got message like this:
"line": 55,
"function": "handle",
"class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
"type": "->"
},
{
"file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pipastibisa\\server.php",
"line": 21,
"function": "require_once"
}
]
}

Comment: @SatriaChasana could you update your question to see the error you get? It might be a typo, this should work.